# Prototypal in heritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

Below is the Javascript object that I have:

```
var calc = {
    title : 'Calculator',
    plus : function( a, b ) {
        return (
           console.log(this),    // calc
           console.log(arguments), // [ 3, 5 ]
           console.log(a+b), // 8
           console.log(this.title) // Calculator
        )
    }
};
```

And I am trying to access the prototype of this object `calc` by the following:

```
calc.prototype.getNum = function( numStr ) {
  return isNaN(parseInt(numStr)) ? 'Not a valid number!' : parseInt(numStr);
};
```

But it keeps giving the following error, whenever I execute it!

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'getNum' of undefined

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you want to add something to the prototype, if you have only one "instance" of your object literal?

Comment: @Bergi because that's what you do, when you are learning something...

Comment: @Bergi BTW, is that a valid reason to downvote?

Comment: No, I didn't downvote.

Comment: If there is ever going to be only one calc then you can leave it as object literal, put all functions in the body of that and forget about prototype. If you're planning to create several calc instances then you may use prototype. For an explanation about prototype and constructor functions you can read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prototype` is a property of functions. It will not be available on object literals. So, you might want to convert the `calc` to a function, like this

```
function calc() {
    this.title = 'Calculator';
}

calc.prototype.plus = function( a, b ) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(a+b);
  console.log(this.title);
}
```

Now, you should be able to add the `getNum` to the prototype of `calc`.

Comment: I will be better to put plus method to prototype ( right now new instance of method will be created for each calc object )

Answer (score -1):

Use calc.constructor.prototype

Comment: As it is the answer might not be very useful to the readers. Could you please explain the answer a bit more?

Comment: No, because `calc.constructor === Object`.

Comment: Nooo you'll be adding to Object.prototype if you do that